# Bind ag-grid with array

Tags: ag-grid

I have an array with values array=[3,4].I have to display the ag-grid values if it matches with array values.This is what i tried so far:

Attached is the plunkr :https://plnkr.co/edit/fKrvfzFYjdLbTLjFkqpY?p=preview

```
 var array=[3,4];
 var columnDefs = [
      {headerName: "Jobs",field: "job", width: 90},
      {headerName: "Location", field: "loc", width: 120 },
      {headerName: "Value", field: "value", width: 120 }];

 var rowData =[{job:'Developer',loc:'X',value:1},
            {job: 'Manager',loc:'Y',value:2},
            {job: 'Musician',loc:'Z',value:3},
            {job: 'Manager',loc:'A',value:4},
            {job: 'Tester',loc:'B',value:5},
            {job: 'DBA',loc:'C',value:6}
       ];

var gridOptions = {
defaultColDef: {
    sortable: true
},
columnDefs: columnDefs,
animateRows: true,
enableRangeSelection: true,
rowData: rowData,
checkbox : true
};
```

How to display the grid when value field value matches with array values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plunkr with a working example - https://plnkr.co/edit/xdwI0Tql9I5n71D4QSDy?p=preview

Add a custom cellRenderer function like so in the column definition of values column

```
{
  headerName: "Value",
  field: "value",
  width: 120,
  cellRenderer: params => array.includes(params.value) ? params.value : ''
}
```